# To find out the minimum required jumper number between objects

Tags: graph-theory

I try to find out the minimum required jumper number for connection between objects. The rule is : all objects are on a plane and need to connect all objects with only one connection. The minimum number of jumpers on other connections are need to be used while creating a connection.

As you see in the picture below, I demonstrated for $n=4,5,6$ but I do not know for $n>6$.

If I define $a_n$ for the minimum jumper number for $n$ object connection..

What is the general formula for $a_n$ ?

Some known values:
$$a_2=0$$
$$a_3=0$$
$$a_4=0$$
$$a_5=1$$
$$a_6=3$$ 
(Maybe $a_6$ is not $3$, Please let me know if you know a solution less than $3$. I found that way for minimum jumpers as shown in picture.)

Note: I do not know the related tags and subject in math. Please  fell free retag the question or advice and give references if it is a known problem.

[image]

Comment: What if one connection intersects two others?

Comment: I trust that you want to connect all nodes to all other nodes. If that's right, then the thing you're looking for has some name like the "genus" of the complete graph on $n$ nodes.

Comment: Link for genus of a graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Graph_theory

Comment: This looks like the crossing number of the complete graph http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCrossingNumber.html

Comment: There is a conjectured formula there in the link I just gave.